# React-native check box logic

Tags: javascript, react-native, switch-statement, react-hooks

I have a check box , if the check box is selected I want to add the checkbox name to an array , when it's unselected I want to remove it from the array and unselect it. I have tried something but it's buggy. Please can someone help me and if there is a better way please suggest .

This is my code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { CheckBox, Button } from "react-native-elements";
const Occasion = props => {
    const [tags, setTags] = useState([]);
    //Checks
    const [today, setToday] = useState(false);
    const [tommorow, setTommorow] = useState(false);
    const [someDay, setSome] = useState(false);
    const CustomCheck = (props) => {
        const { checked, title, onSelect } = props;
        return (
            <CheckBox
                checked={checked}
                onPress={onSelect}
                title={title}
            />
        );
    };
    const handleChecked = (item) => {
        const existingIndex = tags.findIndex(
            tag => tag === item
        );
        switch(item){
            case 'Now':
                setToday(!today)
                if (existingIndex >= 0) {
                    const filteredItems = tags.filter(tag => tag !== item)
                    return setTags(filteredItems)
                }else{
                    setTags(tags.concat(item))
                }
            case 'Tommorow':
                setTommorow(!tommorow)
                if (existingIndex >= 0) {
                    const filteredItems = tags.filter(tag => tag !== item)
                    return setTags(filteredItems)
                }else{
                    setTags(tags.concat(item))
                }
            case 'SomeDay':
                setSome(!someDay)
                if (existingIndex >= 0) {
                    const filteredItems = tags.filter(tag => tag !== item)
                    return setTags(filteredItems)
                }else{
                    setTags(tags.concat(item))
                }
            default: 
                return null
        }

    }
    console.log('tags is', tags)
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <CustomCheck title="Now" checked={today} onSelect={() => {handleChecked("Now") }} />
            <CustomCheck title="Tommorow" checked={tommorow} onSelect={() => { handleChecked("Tommorow") }} />
            <CustomCheck title="SomeDay" checked={someDay} onSelect={() => { handleChecked("SomeDay") }} />
        </View>
    );
};

export default Occasion;
```

Comment: whats the bug? whats the context?

Comment: It is only adding to the array when I uncheck the check box instead of checking it and adding it. Plus If I click `Now` sometimes `Tommorow` also gets clicked maybe because of switch case . Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: This code already has an error, where ```comfort, kid, dinner``` are defined?

Comment: @SaachiTech Sorry about that , that was an error on my part. I fixed it . It was supposed to be, today, tommorow..... Please can you see where I am going wrong and if there is a better way to do this

Comment: Please try this and let me know if this works https://snack.expo.io/@saachitech/react-native-tag

Comment: Oh my goodness it worked. Thank you so much!!!!!!!